# How do I reference my Azure function from pytest?

Tags: python-3.x, import, azure-functions, pytest, python-import

I'm using Python 3.8 with Azure functions.  I have the following project layout ...

```
myproject
    __app__
        __init__.py
        objects
            __init__.py
    tests
        __init__.py
        functions
            __init__.py
            objects
                __init__.py
                test_objects.py
```

My **app**/objects/**init**.py file starts like this ...

```
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    """."""
    ...
```

And then my tests/functions/objects/**init**.py looks like

```
import pytest
import azure.functions as func

_import = __import__('__app__/objects')

def test_objects():
    ...
```

However, when I run

```
pytest tests/functions/test_objects.py
```

I get the error

```
tests/functions/test_objects.py:8: in <module>
    _import = __import__('__app__/objects')
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__app__/objects'
```

What's the right way to reference my function?  I also tried just "objects", but that results in the same ModuleNotFoundError.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#unit-testing) I saw that the functions are imported directly, i.e.:

```py
# tests/test_httptrigger.py
import unittest

import azure.functions as func
from __app__.HttpTrigger import my_function
```

Maybe you could try to reference your tests like this:

```py
# tests/test_objects.py
import unittest

import azure.functions as func
from __app__.objects import main
```

+++ Update +++

Now I've tried to do it on my own and stumbled upon a similar error. After some googling, I've also found an open issue for this at [github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/469).

+++ Update 2 +++

I've managed to get it running by adding an empty `__init__.py` file to the tests folder. Another thing to mention is, that I've adapted to the folder structure in the abovementioned docs and ran the following request in the root folder:
`pytest .`

As a result, the test was executed successfully. Here's an example repository I've created:
[github.com/DSpirit/azure-functions-python-unit-testing](https://github.com/DSpirit/azure-functions-python-unit-testing)