# Run Azure Function outside of functions runtime to allow for pytest testing

Tags: python, azure-functions, pytest

I have an Azure Function App (Python Programming Model V2) that I am trying to trigger outside of the Azure Functions runtime (with my goal being to use `pytest` to test the function). However, when not running in Azure Functions locally using `func host start`, the decorator for the function is preventing it from being run.

How can I trigger the function outside of the Azure Functions runtime to allow me to test it?

---

Take the example below. When I run the function locally and trigger it using cURL, as expected, the desired response is successfully returned

#### `example_project/function_app.py`

```py
import azure.functions as func

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route='HttpTrigger')
def HttpTrigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return func.HttpResponse('Success', status_code=200)
```

```bash
user@computer:~/example_project$ curl http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger
Success
```

However, if I run the function directly nothing happens. In the example below I would expect an error because a required keywork (`req`) is missing. Instead, it seems as though the function wasn't triggered at all.

```py
>>> from example_project.function_app import HttpTrigger
>>> HttpTrigger()
>>>
```

Now if I were to comment out the decorator from `example_project/function_app.py`, you can see that the function is run and an error occurred.

```py
# @app.route(route='HttpTrigger')
```

```py
>>> from example_project.function_app import HttpTrigger
>>> HttpTrigger()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: HttpTrigger() missing 1 required positional argument: 'req'
>>>
```

Comment: Is something preventing you from putting the function body in a separate function and testing that?

Comment: No, I suppose not in the case of unit tests. I'd still like to understand exactly what's happening though, and know if there is a way to change the behaviour through the definition of `app`.

Comment: tried this sample code ```import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return func.HttpResponse('Hello from Azure Function!', status_code=200)
``` [httpOutpt](https://i.imgur.com/9cQlPPC.png) unittest[Output](https://i.imgur.com/bzENrP9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#unit-testing) for Pytest and will give sample reference how to Pytest testing with V2.

> How can I trigger the function outside of the Azure Functions runtime to allow me to test it?

In order for your function to run, It requires Azure Function run time by Azure Function Core tools to run at the back end. It is not possible to trigger the Function without a runtime. Though you can just check or mock the code of your `app.py` separately with your Function but it will just give you the code behavior not how it behaves in runtime.

According to this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#unit-testing) You are required to have your test file path specified in order to call it with your function.

[Folder structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#folder-structure) :

```
<project_root>/
 | - .venv/
 | - .vscode/
 | - function_app.py
 | - additional_functions.py
 | - tests/
 | | - test_my_function.py
```

**Issue:**

[image]

[image]

- We can only trigger the function in the respective path we have configured. The function triggered by `func start` (or)`func host start`. If we run only `app.py` we face might face an issue since there are no function dependency files/no longer acts as a function. For more details refer to [Programming model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#programming-model) and Azure Functions File and Folder [Structure](https://marcroussy.com/2018/12/01/azure-functions-v2-structure/). You need to configure the path to your pytest file in order to run the pytest with the Function trigger.

```py
import  azure.functions  as  func
app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
@app.route(route="HttpTrigger",  methods=["GET"])
def  HttpTrigger(req:  func.HttpRequest)  ->  func.HttpResponse:
return  func.HttpResponse("Success",  status_code=200)
```

```py
import  os
import  sys
import  unittest
import  azure.functions  as  func

sys.path.insert(0,  os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),  "..")))
from  function_app  import  HttpTrigger
class  TestHttpTrigger(unittest.TestCase):
def  test_http_trigger_success(self):
req = func.HttpRequest(
method='GET',
body=None,
url='/api/HttpTrigger',
)
func_call = HttpTrigger.build().get_user_function()
resp = func_call(req)
self.assertEqual(resp.get_body(),  b'Success')
self.assertEqual(resp.status_code,  200)
if  __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

```
<project_root>/
  ├── tests/
  │   ├── test_function_app.py
  ├── function_app.py
```

[image]

[image]

- For more details reference Python for [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators) pytest and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64377567/how-do-i-reference-my-azure-function-from-pytest).Hope it helps.